# Product uploading is too slow on woocommerce using WP All Import plugin

Tags: woocommerce, wpallimport

Please help me to improve product upload speed on WooCommerce store. When uploads around 2000 products its take too much time. I am using Wp All Import plugin for import products. My development store url is: https://dev4.nutrabay.com